# Why $\lambda=0$ if $\lambda\perp \lambda$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Rudin-RCA p.121

> Let $(X,\mathfrak{M})$ be a measurable space.
>   Let $\mu, \lambda$ be (complex) measures on $(X,\mathfrak{M})$ such that $\lambda \ll \mu$ and $\lambda \perp \mu$. Then, $\lambda=0$.

Clearly $\lambda\perp \lambda$. Hence $\lambda(X)=0$. But I think this does not imply that $\lambda(E)=0$ for all $E\in\mathfrak{M}$. Why is $\lambda=0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recheck what $\lambda \perp \mu$ means. It means that there are disjoint (measurable) sets $A,B$ such that $\lambda$ is concentrated on $A$ and $\mu$ is concentrated on $B$, i.e. $\lambda(E) = 0$ whenever $E \cap A = \varnothing$, and $\mu(E) = 0$ whenever $E\cap B = \varnothing$. If $\lambda = \mu$, we can write

$$E = (E\cap A) \cup (E\setminus A)$$

to deduce $\lambda(E) = 0$, where $\lambda(E\cap A) = 0$ because $\lambda$ is concentrated on $B \subset \complement A$, and $\lambda(E\setminus A) = 0$ because $\lambda$ is concentrated on $A$.